# How to perform Batch Insert/Update operations using MyBatis/ iBatis Annotations in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to perform bulk insertion/ update operation for the very first time. I'm using Mybatis Annotaions (Mappers) to carry out database related operations.

I have a @Param which is `List<Map<String, String>> recordList` and looks something like:

```
[{record_no=1, first_name="Alpha", last_name="Tester", age=23, gender="female"},
 {record_no=2, first_name="Beta", last_name="Tester", age=21, gender="male"}]
```

Mapper would have:

```
@Insert({"<script>", 
    "insert into  demo_record (first_name, last_name, age, gender, record_no) values ",
    "<foreach collection='recordList' item='record' index='index' open='(' separator = '),
     ( close=')' > <Here I do not know how to pass/ access Map's values.
                   Would it be just #{first_name} or something else?>
    </foreach>",
    "</script>"})
void doBatchInsert(@Param("recordList") List<Map<String, String>> recordList);
```

**** I'm not sure what exactly `open='(' separator = '), ( close=')'` does as well. I'd greatly appretiate it If someone can shed a light on it. ****

I'm following @Repository -> @Service and then @Autowire RecordService.java

for example Controller class has:

```
@Autowired 
private RecordService recordservice;
.
.

recordservice.doBatchInsert(recordList);
.
.

return "success";
```

Also, how many bulk insertion of records above approch would be able to hadle? (records could range from 5000 to 50000)

**P.S.** :- This is also my first time posting a question here. Please go easy on me, if I've failed to post the question correctly! Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: Can't you use spring-batch for this? It is more appropriate: https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch

Comment: No, I can't. It would be a new add-on to the existing project's structure. Also, just for one single perpose usage it would be unneccesary over-load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this FAQ for a recommendation on coding batch inserts: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert

What you are showing is not a batch - it is one giant insert statement. If you truly will have 5000 to 50000 records, then you will hit the limit of parameters allowed for a JDBC prepared statement very quickly. It would be better to use a true JDBC batch as described in the FAQ.

Comment: I'm aware of the approch you are referring to, but I didn't know how to define my "SqlSessionDaoSupport" constructor that takes "ExecutorType" as "Batch". Can you tell me How to set it to "Batch" in folllowing manner
<bean id="recordsdao" class="com.demo.test.daoimpl.RecordsDaoImpl">
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

Should I add  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" index="1" value="BATCH" /> to the above bean? How does it work? Their documentation is missing this part to define "Batch" when using "SqlSessionDaoSupport" class.

Comment: All you need to do is inject the SqlSessionFactory into your service, then you can use the code as shown in the FAQ. There's a complete working example here: https://github.com/jeffgbutler/PCFDemos/tree/master/mybatis-mysql

Comment: It's working. Now, I'm able to perform batch operation. Thanks!!